# Set background of imageview with else if statement

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to set the background of an imageview using the following code:

```
String color = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR)));
            ImageView background=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.album_image);
            DecodeTask task = (DecodeTask)background.getTag(R.id.album_image);
            background.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            String imageCheck = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_IMAGE)));
            if (imageCheck != 0){
                 background.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageCheck));
            }
            else if (color != null && !color.isEmpty()){
                if (color.equals("1")){
                    task = new DecodeTask(background);
                    background.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebg);
                }
                else if (color.equals("2")){
                    task = new DecodeTask(background);
                    background.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbg);
                }
                else if (color.equals("3")){
                    task = new DecodeTask(background);
                    background.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowbg);
                }
                else if (color.equals("4")){
                    task = new DecodeTask(background);
                    background.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbg);
                }
                else if (color.equals("5")){
                    task = new DecodeTask(background);
                    background.setImageResource(R.drawable.purplebg);
                }
            }
```

However when imageCheck is equal to 0, it doesnt read the further code and sets the default background for the image. What should i do?

Comment: Comparing a string with an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
if(imageCheck != 0)
```

to

```
if(!imageCheck.equals("0"))
```

since you're comparing a String